# Missing permissions required by BaseAdView.loadAd: android.permission.INTERNET

Tags: android, permissions, admob

Why does it give me this error **although I have added all permission needed**?

[image: The error]

[image: the permissions is added already]

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @KKH i ignored it, it doesn`t affect the build process, so it seems to be a bug from the android studio itself

Comment: That works. Thank you :)

Answer (score -2):

remove this code

- in `maifests` file

  ```
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
         android:value="your admob application id"
  ```

Comment: Results in the (expected) error that a valid app ID should be added to the manifest, also does not fix the lint error from OP